# Can't execute binaries in a mounted ext filesystem, why?

Tags: mount, permissions

I recently moved some files from ntfs to ext4 in my external disk. I am not able to run executable files after I convert it to ext4.

1. Below is the fstab entry I use to mount the ext4 partition.

   ```
   UUID={UUID} {path} ext4 rw,async,suid,dev,exec,user 1 1
   ```
2. Below is the permission for the file I am trying to run

   ```
   -rwxrwxrwx 1 {myid} {myid} 73015 Oct  9 09:38 eclipse
   ```
3. When I try to run the program from command line, I get following error message
   bash: ./eclipse: Permission denied
4. When I try to run the program from Nautilus, I get a message that 'There is no application installed for executable files'.
5. I checked the permissions tab in the file properties and the 'Allow executing file as program' bit is set.

Comment: Close voters: why is this no reproducible? This question has all the information needed to reproduce the problem and is already answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue got resolved by changing the mount option from 'user' to 'nouser'. I have not idea why though...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @qbi why not? Care to explain?

Comment: @qbi I posted it as an answer because that was the solution for my issue. By changing the fstab option, I am able to run the executable from the external disk.

Comment: This solution works. Please mark it as accepted answer.

since ext4 rw,async,suid,dev,exec,nouser is equivalent to defaults, you can directly write it as

UUID={UUID} {path} ext4 defaults 1 1

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding "exec" to the entry in /etc/fstab, keeping "user."  There are many combinations of settings here, but this is one set that works.

```
UUID="4blahblah4" /160/  ext4   user,exec,auto,nofail       0       0
```